# 3D Texture Only interpolates on Y-Axis

Tags: c#, directx11, slimdx

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around what actually is the issue here, but the sampler I'm using in my volume renderer is only interpolating the 3D texture along the Y axis.

I roughly followed (and borrowed a lot of code from) this tutorial, but I'm using SlimDX and WPF: http://graphicsrunner.blogspot.com/2009/01/volume-rendering-101.html

Here's an example, showing voxel artifacts on the X and Z axes, which are evidently not being interpolated, or being done incorrectly:

[image: Voxel Artifacts]

It's somewhat hard to tell, but the Y-axis samples are seemingly being interpolated correctly:

[image: Y-Axis Interpolation]

Disabling interpolation in the sampler causes artifacts to appear on the Y-axis, as shown below. So I at least know it's partially working.

[image: Y-Axis Points]

I tried writing a manual trilinear interpolation routine, but I get the same results with built-in sampling and my own code.

To get a better idea of what might be the problem, I tried coloring pixels based on the fraction of the coordinate in grid space, to see why the linear interpolation wasn't working. The Y-axis should have 30 white-> black fades, because the radar dataset I'm volume rendering has 30 vertical layers. It did:

[image: Vertical Layers]

Using the same approach on the Z-axis, I get nonsense:

[image: Horizontal Layers]

My best guess is that I'm somehow initializing the 3D texture incorrectly, causing the shader to act unexpectedly.

Here's relevant code, starting at ingestion of data:

```
// Read data file and get physical sizes
Data = new GURUGridFile(@"E:\GURU2 Test Data\GoshenDual\Finished\30_DOW7_(X)_20090605_220006.ggf");
double DataX = Data.CellSize[0] * Data.Dimensions[0];
double DataY = Data.CellSize[1] * Data.Dimensions[1];
double DataZ = Data.CellSize[2] * Data.Dimensions[2];
double MaxSize = Math.Max(DataX, Math.Max(DataY, DataZ));

// Send geometry sizes to the renderer
DataX /= MaxSize;
DataY /= MaxSize;
DataZ /= MaxSize;
Renderer.XSize = (float)DataX;
Renderer.YSize = (float)DataY;
Renderer.ZSize = (float)DataZ;

// Grab data and read into a 3D array
int ProductCode = Data.LayerProducts[0].ToList().IndexOf("A_DZ");
float[,,] RadarData = new float[Data.Dimensions[0], Data.Dimensions[1], Data.Dimensions[2]];
for (int x = 0; x < Data.Dimensions[0]; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < Data.Dimensions[1]; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < Data.Dimensions[2]; z++)
            RadarData[x, y, z] = Data.Data[z][ProductCode][x, y];

// Calculate and assign the step size for raycasting
// Z and Y axes are flipped here to come in line with D3D coordinates
int DataSize = Math.Max(RadarData.GetLength(0), Math.Max(RadarData.GetLength(1), RadarData.GetLength(2)));
int mWidth = RadarData.GetLength(0);
int mHeight = RadarData.GetLength(2);
int mDepth = RadarData.GetLength(1);
float mStepScale = 1.0F;
float maxSize = (float)Math.Max(mWidth, Math.Max(mHeight, mDepth));
SlimDX.Vector3 stepSize = new SlimDX.Vector3(   1.0f / (mWidth * (maxSize / mWidth)),
                                                1.0f / (mHeight * (maxSize / mHeight)),
                                                1.0f / (mDepth * (maxSize / mDepth)));

// Make render engine
VolumeRenderer = new VolumeRenderEngine(false, Renderer.device);
VolumeRenderer.Data = VolumeRenderTest.Rendering.TextureObject3D.FromData(RadarData);
VolumeRenderer.StepSize = stepSize * mStepScale;
VolumeRenderer.Iterations = (int)(maxSize * (1.0f / mStepScale) * 2.0F);

Renderer.Initialize();
SetupSlimDX();

this.VolumeRenderer.DataWidth = Data.Dimensions[0];
this.VolumeRenderer.DataHeight = Data.Dimensions[2];
this.VolumeRenderer.DataDepth = Data.Dimensions[1];
```

Here's my code to generate the 3D texture, wrapped in a helper class to make working with it more convenient. This is where I think my problem is, maybe?

```
public static TextureObject3D FromData(float[,,] Data)
{
    Texture3DDescription texDesc = new Texture3DDescription()
    {
        BindFlags = SlimDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.ShaderResource,
        CpuAccessFlags = SlimDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
        Format = SlimDX.DXGI.Format.R32_Float,
        MipLevels = 1,
        OptionFlags = SlimDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
        Usage = SlimDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Default,
        Width = Data.GetLength(0),
        Height = Data.GetLength(2),
        Depth = Data.GetLength(1)
    };

    // Flatten data
    int i = 0;
    float[] FlatData = new float[Data.GetLength(0) * Data.GetLength(1) * Data.GetLength(2)];
    for (int y = 0; y < Data.GetLength(1); y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < Data.GetLength(2); z++)
            for (int x = 0; x < Data.GetLength(0); x++)
                FlatData[i++] = Data[x, y, z];


    DataStream TextureStream = new DataStream(FlatData, true, true);
    DataBox TextureBox = new DataBox(texDesc.Width * 4, texDesc.Width * texDesc.Height * 4, TextureStream);
    Texture3D valTex = new Texture3D(Renderer.device, texDesc, TextureBox);

    var viewDesc = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceViewDescription()
    {
        Format = texDesc.Format,
        Dimension = SlimDX.Direct3D11.ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture3D,
        MipLevels = texDesc.MipLevels,
        MostDetailedMip = 0,
        ArraySize = 1,
        CubeCount = 1,
        ElementCount = 1
    };
    ShaderResourceView valTexSRV = new ShaderResourceView(Renderer.device, valTex, viewDesc);

    TextureObject3D tex = new TextureObject3D();
    tex.Device = Renderer.device;

    tex.Size = TextureStream.Length;
    tex.TextureStream = TextureStream;
    tex.TextureBox = TextureBox;
    tex.Texture = valTex;
    tex.TextureSRV = valTexSRV;

    return tex;
}
```

This is the code from the render engine where values are assigned to the effect and instructions are sent to the GPU:

```
private void RenderVolume()
{
    // Rasterizer states
    RasterizerStateDescription RSD_Front = new RasterizerStateDescription();
    RSD_Front.FillMode = SlimDX.Direct3D11.FillMode.Solid;
    RSD_Front.CullMode = CullMode.Back;
    RSD_Front.IsFrontCounterclockwise = false;

    RasterizerStateDescription RSD_Rear = new RasterizerStateDescription();
    RSD_Rear.FillMode = SlimDX.Direct3D11.FillMode.Solid;
    RSD_Rear.CullMode = CullMode.Front;
    RSD_Rear.IsFrontCounterclockwise = false;

    RasterizerState RS_OLD = Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.State;
    RasterizerState RS_FRONT = RasterizerState.FromDescription(Renderer.device, RSD_Front);
    RasterizerState RS_REAR = RasterizerState.FromDescription(Renderer.device, RSD_Rear);

    // Calculate world view matrix
    Matrix wvp = _world * _view * _proj;

    RenderTargetView NullRTV = null;

    // First we need to render to the rear texture
    SetupBlend(false);
    PrepareRTV(RearTextureView);
    SetBuffers();
    Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.State = RS_REAR;
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_WVP.SetMatrix(wvp);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_ScaleFactor.Set(ScaleFactor);
    ExecuteTechnique(Renderer.RayCasting101FX_RenderPosition);
    Device.ImmediateContext.Flush();
    Device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(NullRTV);

    // Now we draw to the front texture
    SetupBlend(false);
    PrepareRTV(FrontTextureView);
    SetBuffers();
    Device.ImmediateConte﻿xt.Rasterizer.State = RS_FRONT;
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_WVP.SetMatrix(wvp);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_ScaleFactor.Set(ScaleFactor);
    ExecuteTechnique(Renderer.RayCasting101FX_RenderPosition);
    Device.ImmediateContext.Flush();
    Device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(NullRTV);


    SetupBlend(false);

    //Set Render Target View
    Device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(SampleRenderView);

    // Set Viewport
    Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewports(new Viewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    // Clear screen
    Device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(SampleRenderView, new Color4(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F));

    if (Wireframe)
    {
        RenderWireframeBack();
        Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.State = RS_FRONT;
    }

    SetBuffers();

    // Assign effect variables
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_WVP.SetMatrix(wvp);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_ScaleFactor.Set(ScaleFactor);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_Back.SetResource(new ShaderResourceView(Renderer.device, RearTexture));// RearTextureSRV);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_Front.SetResource(new ShaderResourceView(Renderer.device, FrontTexture));//FrontTextureSRV);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_Volume.SetResource(new ShaderResourceView(Renderer.device, Data.Texture));
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_StepSize.Set(StepSize);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_Iterations.Set(Iterations);

    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_Width.Set(DataWidth);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_Height.Set(DataHeight);
    Renderer.RayCasting101FX_Depth.Set(DataDepth);

    // Run effect
    ExecuteTechnique(Renderer.RayCasting101FX_RayCastSimple);

    if (Wireframe)
    {
        RenderWireframeFront();
        Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.State = RS_FRONT;
    }

    Device.ImmediateContext.Flush();

    CanvasInvalid = false;

    sw.Stop();

    this.LastFrame = sw.ElapsedTicks / 10000.0;
}


private void PrepareRTV(RenderTargetView rtv)
{
    //Set Depth Stencil and Render Target View
    Device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(rtv);

    // Set Viewport
    Device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewports(new Viewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    // Clear render target
    Device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(rtv, new Color4(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F));
}

private void SetBuffers()
{
    // Setup buffer info
    Device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.InputLayout = Renderer.RayCastVBLayout;
    Device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
    Device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(Renderer.VertexBuffer, Renderer.VertexPC.Stride, 0));
    Device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(Renderer.IndexBuffer, Format.R32_UInt, 0);
}

private void ExecuteTechnique(EffectTechnique T)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < T.Description.PassCount; p++)
    {
        T.GetPassByIndex(p).Apply(Device.ImmediateContext);
        Device.ImmediateContext.DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the shader in its entirety. Taken from the blog post above and modified somewhat.

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 WorldViewProj;
float4x4 WorldInvTrans;

float3 StepSize;
int Iterations;

int Side;

float4 ScaleFactor;

int Width;
int Height;
int Depth;

Texture2D<float3> Front;
Texture2D<float3> Back;
Texture3D<float1> Volume;

SamplerState FrontSS = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Front>;
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;

    AddressU = Border; // border sampling in U
    AddressV = Border; // border sampling in V
    BorderColor = float4(0, 0, 0, 0); // outside of border should be black
};

SamplerState BackSS = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Back>;
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;

    AddressU = Border; // border sampling in U
    AddressV = Border; // border sampling in V
    BorderColor = float4(0, 0, 0, 0); // outside of border should be black
};


SamplerState VolumeSS = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Volume>;
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;


    AddressU = Border; // border sampling in U
    AddressV = Border; // border sampling in V
    AddressW = Border; // border sampling in W
    BorderColor = float4(0, 0, 0, 0); // outside of border should be black
};


struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float3 Position : POSITION;
    float4 texC     : COLOR;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position     : SV_POSITION;
    float3 texC         : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 pos          : TEXCOORD1;
};

VertexShaderOutput PositionVS(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    output.Position = float4(input.Position, 1.0);
    output.Position = mul(output.Position * ScaleFactor, WorldViewProj);

    output.texC = input.texC.xyz;
    output.pos = output.Position;

    return output;
}

float4 PositionPS(VertexShaderOutput input) : SV_TARGET // : COLOR0
{
    return float4(input.texC, 1.0f);
}

float4 WireFramePS(VertexShaderOutput input) : SV_TARGET // : COLOR0
{
    return float4(1.0f, .5f, 0.0f, .85f);
}

//draws the front or back positions, or the ray direction through the volume
float4 DirectionPS(VertexShaderOutput input) : SV_TARGET // : COLOR0
{
    float2 texC = input.pos.xy /= input.pos.w;
    texC.x =  0.5f * texC.x + 0.5f;
    texC.y = -0.5f * texC.y + 0.5f;

    float3 front = Front.Sample(FrontSS, texC).rgb;// tex2D(FrontS, texC).rgb;
    float3 back = Back.Sample(BackSS, texC).rgb; // tex2D(BackS, texC).rgb;

    if(Side == 0)
    {
        float4 res = float4(front, 1.0f);
        return res;

    }
    if(Side == 1)
    {
        float4 res = float4(back, 1.0f);
        return res;
    }

    return float4(abs(back - front), 1.0f);
}

float TrilinearSample(float3 pos)
{
    float X = pos.x * Width;
    float Y = pos.y * Height;
    float Z = pos.z * Depth;

    float iX = floor(X);
    float iY = floor(Y);
    float iZ = floor(Z);

    float iXn = iX + 1;
    float iYn = iY + 1;
    float iZn = iZ + 1;

    float XD = X - iX;
    float YD = Y - iY;
    float ZD = Z - iZ;

    float LL = lerp(Volume[float3(iX, iY, iZ)], Volume[float3(iX, iY, iZn)], ZD);
    float LR = lerp(Volume[float3(iXn, iY, iZ)], Volume[float3(iXn, iY, iZn)], ZD);

    float UL = lerp(Volume[float3(iX, iYn, iZ)], Volume[float3(iX, iYn, iZn)], ZD);
    float UR = lerp(Volume[float3(iXn, iYn, iZ)], Volume[float3(iXn, iYn, iZn)], ZD);

    float L = lerp(LL, UL, YD);
    float R = lerp(LR, UR, YD);

    //return ZD;

    return lerp(L, R, XD);

    return 0.0F;
}

float4 RayCastSimplePS(VertexShaderOutput input) : SV_TARGET // : COLOR0
{ 
    //calculate projective texture coordinates
    //used to project the front and back position textures onto the cube
    float2 texC = input.pos.xy /= input.pos.w;
    texC.x =  0.5f* texC.x + 0.5f;
    texC.y = -0.5f* texC.y + 0.5f;

    float3 front = Front.Sample(FrontSS, texC).rgb; // tex2D(FrontS, texC).xyz;
    float3 back = Back.Sample(BackSS, texC).rgb; // tex2D(BackS, texC).xyz;

    float3 dir = normalize(back - front);
    float4 pos = float4(front, 0);

    float4 dst = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float4 src = 0;

    float value = 0;

    //Iterations = 1500;

    float3 Step = dir * StepSize; // / (float)Iterations;
    float3 TotalStep = float3(0, 0, 0);

    value = Volume.Sample(VolumeSS, pos.xyz).r;

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
    {
        pos.w = 0;
        //value = Volume.SampleLevel(VolumeSS, pos.xyz, 0);
        value = TrilinearSample(pos.xyz); // tex3Dlod(VolumeS, pos).r;

        // Radar reflectivity related threshold values
        if (value < 40)
            value = 40;
        if (value > 60)
            value = 60;

        value = (value - 40.0) / 20.0;

        src =  (float4)(value);
        src.a /= (Iterations / 50.0);

        //Front to back blending
        // dst.rgb = dst.rgb + (1 - dst.a) * src.a * src.rgb
        // dst.a   = dst.a   + (1 - dst.a) * src.a      
        src.rgb *= src.a;
        dst = (1.0f - dst.a) * src + dst;

        //break from the loop when alpha gets high enough
        if (dst.a >= .95f)
            break;

        //advance the current position
        pos.xyz += Step;
        TotalStep += Step;

        //break if the position is greater than <1, 1, 1>
        if (pos.x > 1.0f || pos.y > 1.0f || pos.z > 1.0f || pos.x < 0.0f || pos.y < 0.0f || pos.z < 0.0f)
            break;
    }

    return dst;
}


technique11 RenderPosition
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, PositionVS()));
        SetGeometryShader(NULL);
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, PositionPS()));
        //VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 PositionVS();
        //PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PositionPS();
    }
}

technique11 RayCastDirection
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, PositionVS()));
        SetGeometryShader(NULL);
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, DirectionPS()));
        //VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 PositionVS();
        //PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 DirectionPS();
    }
}

technique11 RayCastSimple
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, PositionVS()));
        SetGeometryShader(NULL);
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, RayCastSimplePS()));
        //VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 PositionVS();
        //PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 RayCastSimplePS();
    }
}

technique11 WireFrame
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, PositionVS()));
        SetGeometryShader(NULL);
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, WireFramePS()));
        //VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 PositionVS();
        //PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 WireFramePS();
    }
}
```

Any insight is appreciated. At this point I'm just guessing at possible issues and seeing what changes. Mostly just breaking things though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It had absolutely nothing to do with the Texture3D, sampler, or anything else that I was wanting to blame.

Upon zooming in really far, I noticed that it probably wasn't the 3D texture's fault - it looked like the ray directions were being somehow miscalculated. The pixelated areas are looking slightly different directions from each other, causing tight gradients to get broken up.

[image: Bad Directions]

It turns out issue was the textures I was drawing the front/rear faces of the geometry to. They were initialized as B8G8R8A8_UNorm. As soon as I changed them to R32G32B32A32_Float it worked. It was just insufficient precision all along.

Now it works properly:

[image: Working!]

Live and learn!